# using QMediaPlayer on Windows system with code compiled on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, mxe

A [project](https://github.com/suizokukan/freedipylonreader) of mine is written with Qt5/c++, using the QMediaPlayer class to read audio files. Everything's ok as long as I run this project on Linux.
Since I want to run my program on Windows, I use [MXE](http://mxe.cc/) to compile my code and create a binary file for Windows systems.

The program seems ok, except this problem with the QMediaPlayer class. When the program runs on a Windows system, I read this message :

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer".
```

By googling around, I came to understand that the QMediaPlayer used [several plugins](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Multimedia_Backends), different on each platform. On Windows, The WMF plugin is Microsoft-only, DirectShow seems useless; others [suggest](http://www.qtfr.org/viewtopic.php?id=16522) to use other external plugins like portaudio, SdlAudio ou OpenAI.

How may I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and know how to fix it : [according to this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/mingw-cross-env-list/2013-06/msg00027.html), just add the following line to your .pro file :

```
QTPLUGIN += dsengine qtmedia_audioengine
```